# Is printing the image of an idol forbidden?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

For example a Greek deity. Would printing an image of one count as making an image of an idol, even if it's not meant for worship? For example if it's printed for an article.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not.

Greek deities are out of worship from a long time.

Additionally to make a non relief image  is not really a reproduction and is obviously not  made for worship.

See  SA YD 146, 10:

> הניחוה עובדיה והלכו להם בשעת שלום מותרת בשעת מלחמה אסורה והוא שאינם יכולים לחזור לה אבל אם היו יכולים לחזור לה ולא חזרו מותרת: ‏
>
> If idolaters abandoned it in time of peace it is allowed for profit.

A fortiori it's allowed to photograph it and to print it

Comment: Not to mention that when one prints a picture of a Greek or Roman deity it is usually for educational purposes.

Comment: @Ezra Hoerster yes you are referring to Rabban Gamliel להתלמד שאני good

Comment: @kouty. Not every educational purposes is permitted. Maybe li'havin u'lihoros (and li'hislamed) implies only for religious purposes.

Comment: @MarkA.  I had the same doubt and therefore not included it in the answer

Comment: It could be the Ramban would prohibit taking a photograph of such a thing,tzarich iyun

Comment: @sam where is the Ramban?